# How can I bind quantity (input of type number) and item (input of type checkbox) in HTML?

Tags: php, html, input

I have a list of dynamically generated items (in PHP) and I have to let the user to chose a quantity for each item, how can I bind (and distinguish) each input of type number to corresponding item?
Each item has a code as attribute "value" and I could give names (attribute "name") like "numitems_".$itemcode to input tags of but I'm not sure this is a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this.

I would set the name of the inputs to an array:

```
echo '<input type="number" name="numitems['.$itemcode.']" />';
```

Then you can check it like this:

```
foreach($_POST['numitems'] as $code => $number){
  echo 'Value of '.$code.' is: '.$number;
}
```